# Slow boot from purple screen on, cold start only

Tags: boot, 18.04

On 16.04, 18.04 and 19.04 - on a Xeon Workstation, the OS on an SSD with a Firepro V4800 graphics card.  "Cold" starting my PC after the grub beep if enabled - I get a purple screen for up to five minutes or so but usually around three or four.  Ubuntu then starts.

If my PC hasn't been switched off for more than a minute or two - it boots at at normal speed.

I have been going around in circles trying the solutions Googling offers to similar problems, with the exception of rolling back the kernel.

Any help gratefully received.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary, likely culprits of the purple screen hang in my case -  Dell Precision T1650, SSD, Xeon 1270v2, FirePro V4800 – an updated Dell bios and or a particular USB wireless adapter.

I needed the video card the machine was originally supplied with to get the PC to boot following removing and re-inserting the CMOS battery.

And also to turn serr off in the bios settings so my preferred video card would output video whilst booting up.

This followed trying “secure boot” in the bios and ending up with no boot at all – it was swapping the suspect wireless adapter to another machine that worked flawlessly with a different wireless adapter resulting in a load of error messages that  suggested it may have been the cause of the problem in the first place.

I have updated a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 and everything is working as it should.  However after losing from three to ten minutes, to over half an hour every day waiting for my PC to boot besides spending many many hours trying to resolve the issue – to be on the safe side I turned Ubuntu updates off following the initial update with everything working as it should.

Comment: If your issue is solved, please accept your *own* answer, it would help further readers